# Python: opening web browser and returning back to application

Tags: python, browser

The basic use case I want to do is opening a web page from python, after which the user will perform some work on the web page (while python waits), and then the web page will return some info (essentially redirecting to another URL), and python will be able to capture the new web page - and continue executing.

After googling, I have not been able to find a way to do it. Essentially all examples are assuming I am working in batch and I do not need to perform any operation in the background. Does anybody have a hint for me?

Comment: You may want to read https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html which allows one to open a web server from Python.

Comment: @boardrider that module is not allowing me to perform operations in the browser meanwhile my python programme waits.

Answer (score 1):

Use Selenium with Python.You can also choose the browser with help of web drivers. Refer more on http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Quick question, your suggestion is use a "wait" from selenium, if that is the case I have not found any condition that is "http address changed" or similar. Which will be the waiting condition?